# How continue updating screen without flooding onTouchEvent ? (android SurfaceView)

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, sleep, surfaceview

When you have a surfaceView class, used for animation/game/... you have the onTouchEvent() method and the drawing/screen-refreshing method in that same class. Now I want to just sleep the onTouchEvent method, so it doesn't get called +-80 times a second and flooding the cpu (and therefor causing lag). The problem is that if I sleep this class, it also stops drawing/updating/refreshing. What could be a good solution for this?

**Edit**
@tanner, that's indeed what i'm trying, to stop onTouchEvent() to be called too frequently. my attempt:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.d("firstTest",Integer.toString(event.getAction()));   //shows up
    if (!sleeper.CurrentlySleeping) {
        Log.d("2ndTest",Integer.toString(event.getAction())); //not showing up
        ~~  some calculations and stuff  ~~
```

.

```
public class TouchSleeper extends Thread {
// If Thread is sleeping or not.
public static Boolean CurrentlySleeping;
public TouchSleeper() {
    CurrentlySleeping = false;
    this.setPriority(MIN_PRIORITY);
    }

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            CurrentlySleeping = true;
            TouchSleeper.sleep(50);
            CurrentlySleeping = false; }
        ~end~
```

First a piece of code from my SurfaceView class. Second piece of a class/thread, wich keeps changing a boolean value. Note how my first Log.d does return something, and the second one doesn't. This tells me that CurrentlySleeping is never false ? I still have not figured things out... ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();

    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

Also have a look at the [`MotionEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) javadoc for an explanation of the different event types.

By overriding `onTouchEvent`, you can control what happens in that method. You could set a flag in your Activity (`boolean touchEnabled = true`) and do a check in `onTouchEvent()`:

```
if (!touchEnabled) {
    return;
}

// continue with whatever you wanted to do.

// Remove the following line if you don't want to pass the event to the parent.
super.onTouchEvent(event);
```

**UPDATE**

If your issue is simply that the `onTouchEvent()` is firing too fast, then you could do something like this:

```
private long lastTime = -1;

private long threshold = 1000;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (lastTime > -1 && (now - lastTime) < threshold) {
        // Return if a touch event was receive less than "threshold" time ago
        return;
    }

    lastTime = now;

    super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: @usealbarazer I can't really give you an answer until I understand what you're trying to do in your app. What controls when the `onTouchEvent()` should fire off or when it should not? I can tell you that you do not want to loop as you are suggesting, as that would cause the app to become unresponsive. I posted an update to my answer, have a look at that.

Comment: @usealbarazer The update is there now... couldn't get my update to go through at first.

Comment: late question: Isn't there some way to lower the frequency onTouchEvent is even called, instead of just blocking the code inside the methodbody? Cause the main performance drop comes from onTouchEvent() even being called by android so frequently.